# Python skimage daisy different sizes of feature vectors

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am using skimage and sklearn to train a classifier of images of the dataset food101

```
def process_image(image_fp):
image_ = imread(image_fp)
resize(image_, (400, 350)).shape
image=rgb2gray(image_)
descs=skimage.feature.daisy(image, step=180, radius=58, rings=2, histograms=6, orientations=8)
if descs.shape[0]!=3:
    descs=descs.transpose(1, 0, 2)
return descs.reshape(descs.size).tolist()
```

When it comes to:

```
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), parameters).fit(x_train, y_train)
```

It appears an error because of different sizes of the return of the function 'process_image'.

I can solve the problem by selecting only the number of elements of the list with less elements, but I think it may have a more correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you skip resizing the image.

Change this line:

```
resize(image_, (400, 350)).shape
```

To this line:

```
image_ = resize(image_, (400, 350))
```

Final function:

```
def process_image(image_fp):
    image_ = imread(image_fp)
    image_ = resize(image_, (400, 350))
    image=rgb2gray(image_)
    descs=skimage.feature.daisy(image, step=180, radius=58, rings=2, histograms=6, orientations=8)
    if descs.shape[0]!=3:
        descs=descs.transpose(1, 0, 2)
    return descs.reshape(descs.size).tolist()
```

When I change it, the results became like below:

Before changing code:

`Random image size: (445, 578, 3)`

`Daisy vector size: 624`

After changing code:

`Random image size: (400, 350, 3)`

`Daisy vector size: 416`